# XPath function to convert multiple text nodes into a single one

Tags: java, xpath, substring, saxon

I'm using SAXON Java to evaluate an XPath expression which uses substring-after(). This function when gives me the following error when executed against some DOMs:

`A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of substring-after().`

Is there any XPath function to convert multiple text nodes into single one? Here are different XPaths I test:

```
1. substring-after(normalize-space(//*[@id='PrintArea']//div/p[1]//span/font), ':')

2. substring-after(normalize-space(//*[@id='PrintArea']//div/p[1]//span/font[1]), ':')

3. substring-after(//*[@id='PrintArea']//div/p[1]//span/font/text(), ':')

4. substring-after(//*[@id='PrintArea']//div/p[1]//span/font[1]/text(), ':')

5. substring-after(//*[@id='PrintArea']//div/p[1]//span/font/text()[position()=1], ':')

5. substring-after(//*[@id='PrintArea']//div/p[1]//span/font[1]/text()[position()=1], ':')
```

I should also add that Firebug's FirePath evaluates all the above successfully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the first argument (I'll call it ARG) to substring-after contains more than one node, XPath 1.0 will ignore all but the first. If that's the effect you want, change ARG to (ARG)[1] to make this explicit. Note the parentheses: `/a/b/c/text()[1]` won't have the required effect, it needs to be `(/a/b/c/text())[1]`.

There are two other possible interpretations. You might want to say: for each of the text nodes returned by the first argument, return the substring after the first colon. That would be

```
ARG/substring-after(., ':')
```

Or you might want to say: concatenate the text nodes returned by the first argument into a single string, and find the part of this string after the first colon. That would be

```
substring-after(string-join(ARG, ''), ':')
```

So depending on which of these three behaviours you want, choose the syntax to match. XPath 2.0 makes it an error because guessing your intent is dangerous.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your first solution (wrapping the whole XPath in parentheses) woked even without text() (seems that substring-after implicitly casts result to text). BTW, why /a/b/c[1] doesn't work byt (/a/b/c)[1] works? Is there any difference?

Comment: substring-after returns a string, which is not quite the same as a text node. /a/b/c[1] means /a/b/(c[1]), which returns the first c child of every /a/b node.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to convert them into a single string using the [`string-join` function](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/saxon7.7/functions.html#fn%3astring-join) ([spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-string-join)). This will take a list of strings and give your a single string as result. Use the empty string as separator.